# Library Override links broken, how to fix?

Tags: objects, import, blend-files

I was working in a scene last night in Blender 2.90.1, with 3 rigged characters I imported as library overrides. I created a brick wall behind them in the scene and posed them in front of it.

Then this morning when I open the file, none of the library override characters show up, it is only the brick wall. They still show in the outliner but I get an error when the scene loads that says:

"Unable to open "file path" . No such file or directory
"Cannot find lib "***.blend"

It shows that for every object in a big long list. Now I'm not sure why this happened, i didn't change any paths while working on the scene or between last night and this morning. All the files are on a local drive.

And aside from why it happened, if by chance all of my file paths did change, how do i fix the path for the library override to work again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Most external files can be quickly resolved by using File -> External Data -> Find Missing Files, there's options in that submenu for changing the path behavior per .blend.

Linked Libraries are slightly different, they can be re-linked using the Outliner, by switching the Display Mode to "Blender File" and then right-clicking the broken library to Relocate.

This may preserve the Library Override and it's data, but the feature is still being actively improved, so some datablocks may be reset to their linked state.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It turns out i think the whole scene is corrupt as a few items i built and textured in the scene also seemed to lose connection to their textures and were showing up pink until i reconnected them. Even though the path was the same. The relocate feature for the library overrides did work though, but unfortunately while it recovered the characters, it threw them back at their original import state in a t-pose and lost all the animation, :-(

Comment: Don't lose hope on the lost animations just yet :) If you still have an old copy of the scene that has the animation data, you can try re-linking these action blocks to the refreshed, t-posed armatures using the Action Editor. I had to do the same when testing out a broken scene for myself.  

You might see them in the Actions drop-down with "0 Character_action", showing they're still present in the scene but with no users. They may also be visible under the Outliner when you toggle the view to Blender File instead of View Layer. Good luck!

Comment: Ah cool!! yeah Ill give that a shot, thanks!