# Blender 3.0: how to edit material of linked object

Tags: materials, linked-data, library-overrides

In Blender 3.0, I have linked a character (created in another file) into the current scene. I enabled Library Overrides and I can change the pose of the character... but unfortunately I can't change its material (I'm mostly interested to change the base color). Is it possible? I need it to quickly see which color best matches the scene colors.

**EDIT**

I tried the proposed answer, but I get an error "Indirect Library data-block, cannot change".

[image]

Comment: AFAIk library overrides are not supported for materials. The changes are lost when you restart Blender.

Comment: @Gorgious Even in Blender 3.0? Also, since I just want a way to find the appropriate material for my character, it's not a big deal to see the material removed (even if I may be interested later to persist that change)

Answer (score 2):

On the top of the *Material* panel you can click on this *Link* button and choose *Object*, it will create a new material. After that, as mentioned by josephhansen you can unlink a material or create a new one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This kind of work, but I can't create a new material then, I need to use a Material created first in another object. Also, I can't "re-use" the setting of the old material, I need to recreate it from scratch (which may be annoying if the material is complex). Also, any idea if I can reset this override to use the default material once I moved my change back to the linked file? I tried to right click on "My New Material > Remove Override", but it does not reset to the old material.

Comment: mmh that's weird because in my case I can create a new material, use a former one and also unlink a former one, so I'm afraid I don't understand what's happening for you, I hope someone will answer

Answer (score 1):

In your shader editor, click the paperclip icon next to the Material name. This will create a local copy you can edit.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get an error "Indirect Library data-block, cannot change" (see my edit)

Comment: Sounds like you need to relink the link. Try this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206118/library-override-links-broken-how-to-fix

Comment: I tried to reload & relocate, no change.